# Show HSV Values using open cv

Tags: python, opencv

- I have a function in python which takes in RGB values and converts them HSV    values.
- Now I would want to write the Hue component, Value component and Saturation component of this image  into separate images.
- How to    write these images using opencv.

---

- I know that **cv2.imwrite** takes in a 3D array and considers this to be an image in the **RGB** colour space.
- How to tell opencv that it should    consider the HSV colour space and not RGB

Comment: simply write the resultant Mat which is in HSV color space to file using imwrite.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> I would want to write the Hue component, Value component and Saturation component of this image into separate images.

`cv2.imwrite()` actually can write 2D arrays as well.

So, since you already have a 3D HSV array, you can just use something like:

```
cv2.imwrite('hue.png', img[:,:,0])
cv2.imwrite('sat.png', img[:,:,1])
cv2.imwrite('val.png', img[:,:,2])
```

To split them and write the three components as three images.

Comment: Thank you :) I did that.. That was helpful :)